# How to store multiple data into SharedPreference

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences

i have this

```
 mSharedPref.edit().putString("newuser",model.getName()).apply();
```

and this is where im retrieving the data in my `onStart()` method

```
Log.e("ONSTARTUSER",""+ mSharedPref.getString("newuser",null));
```

my output is this

> ONSTARTUSER: Homer Simpson

but i have a collection of names, lets say like 10 names , and i want my shared preferences to display them all when i call the getString("newuser") , how can i do this ? im using `firebaselistadapter`

Comment: Well then you should put all names in it to begin with. And i would change "newuser" to "newusers".

Comment: but im using a list with my database, and i have the users there, and users are adding automatically, so i dont need to do a lot of putStrings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your list to a set:

```
Set<String>usersSet= new HashSet<>(usersList);
```

Then save the set into SharedPreferences:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("newusers", usersSet);
```

And to get them:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences();
    Set<String> usersSet= prefs.getStringSet("newusers", new HashSet<String>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives : use a StringSet with editor.putStringSet() or use a SQLite database.

The database seems the best solution for me to maintain a list of names (or a list of anything), more safe. If for example your app is killed by the system you can lose data with the Shared Prefs.